# Need help analyze Java Thread dump

Tags: java, threadpool

I am using samurai tool to analyze thread dump. It looks like it has many blocked threads. I have no clue to derive anything from the thread dump.

I have an SQL query in my Java application that runs on weblogic that takes enormous time to complete. After running this query by clicking on my Java application button several times hangs my JVM.

Thread dumps can be found @ : http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/379103/biserver2-txt.html

Can you help me understand what does the thread dump say ?

Comment: A *megafileupload* link?? Good luck with that.

Comment: I suggest you remove all the thread from the list which are idle.  This should cut you down to one to four threads which you should be able to paste into this question.

Comment: Is there a quick way to remove all Idle threads as requested above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with WLDF logging information to log file. Once disabled it helped improve performance enormously. I am not a fan of ThreadLogic as a tool for thread dump analysis. It shows circular deadlock when you have stuck threads no matter how variant the issue is.

Answer (score 4):

The amount of data you provide is a bit overwhelming, so let's just give you a hint how to proceed. For the analysis I use open source [threadlogic](http://java.net/projects/threadlogic/downloads) application based on TDA. It takes few seconds to parse 3 MiB worth of data but in nicely shows 22 different stack trace dumps in one file:

[image: Dumps]

Drilling down to reveals really disturbing list of warnings and alerts.

[image: Alerts]

I don't have time to examine all of them, but here is a list of those marked as FATAL (keep in mind that false-positives are also to be expected):

> ## Wait for SLSB Beans
>
> *Description*:  Waiting for Stateless Session Bean (SLSB) instance from the SLSB Free pool
>
> *Advice*: Beans all in use, free pool size size insufficient
>
> ## DEADLOCK
>
> *Description*:  Circular Lock Dependency Detected leading to Deadlock
>
> *Advice*: Deadlock detected with circular dependency in locks, blocked threads will not recover without Server Restart. Fix the order of locking and or try to avoid locks or change order of locking at code level, Report with SR for Server/Product Code
>
> ## Finalizer Thread Blocked
>
> *Description*: Finalizer Thread Blocked
>
> *Advice*: Check if the Finalizer Thread is blocked for a lock which can lead to wasted memory waiting to be reclaimed from Finalizer Queue
>
> ## WLS Unicast Clustering unhealthy
>
> *Description*: Unicast messaging among Cluster members is not healthy
>
> *Advice*: Unicast group members are unable to communicate properly, apply latest Unicast related patches and enable Message Ordering or switch to Multicast
>
> ## WLS Muxer is processing server requests
>
> *Description*: WLS Muxer is handling subsystem requests
>
> *Advice*: WLS Server health is unhealthy as some subsystems are overwhelmed with requests which is leading to the Muxer threads directly handling requests. instead of dispatching to relevant subsystems. There is likely a bug here.
>
> ## Stuck Thread
>
> *Description*: Thread is Stuck, request taking very long time to finish
>
> *Advice*: Check why the thread or call is taking very long??. Is it blocked for unavailable or bad resource or contending for Lock?. Can be ignored if it is doing repeat work in a loop. (like adapter threads polling for events in a infinite loop)...

Comment: If there is a DeadLock, why does Samurai tool that i used not show the Deadlock icon in its GUI ?

Comment: @shifahim: don't know, no tool is perfect. Confront the output of both, maybe you'll find something useful.

Comment: Drilling down to reveals really disturbing list of warnings and alerts. Where and how do you get the snapshot from ? I have TDA tool but no idea where to get that from.

Comment: Also some may be the cause and the others may be the effect of the cause. Is there a way we can zero in the real cause of the issue ?

Comment: @shifahim: I was using *threadlogic* built on top of tda. Use the former one, it has more features. I suppose it should give you an insight which threads are causing issues.

Comment: Thank you forall your help, but if someone could further investigate and help me understand whats ausing my server to hang based on my thread dumps. an you tell me that the deadlock is between which threads?

Comment: The issue was with WLDF logging information to log file. Once disabled it helped improve performance enormously. I am not a fan of ThreadLogic as a tool for thread dump analysis. It shows circular deadlock when you have stuck threads no matter how variant the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Thread dumps are the snapshot of all threads running in the application at given moment. Thread dump will have hundreds/thousands of application threads. It would be hard to scroll through every single line of the stack trace in every single thread. Call Stack Tree consolidates all the threads stack trace into one single tree and gives you one single view. It makes the thread dumps navigation much simpler and easier. Below is the sample call stack tree generated by fastThread.io.

[image]
          Fig 1: Call stack Tree

You can keep drilling down to see code execution path. Fig 2 shows the drilled down version of a particular branch in the Call Stack Tree diagram.

[image]
      Fig 2: Drilled down Call Stack Tree

[Sample call stack tree generated by FastThread.io](https://blog.fastthread.io/2018/04/27/benefits-of-call-stack-tree/)